# ios web service login returns empty xml response

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, web-services

I'm an ios noob.. i'm developing an iphone app that uses a soap web service to do the login operation.
I read lots of similar questions but none helped me.. 
I copy-pasted the soap official code example, changing only the url and the request's xml in order to take username and password from two textviews. Connection is ok and i have http error 200 (not a real error..i know, so the connection is ok) but returned webData object length is 0 bytes and so i have an empty xml response..

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)actBtnLogin:(id)sender {

    recordResults = NO;

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope "
                             "xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" "
                             "xmlns:ns1=\"urn:dbmanager\" "
                             "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" "
                             "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" "
                             "xmlns:ns2=\"http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap\" "
                             "xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" "
                             "SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\"> "
                             "<SOAP-ENV:Body> "
                             "<ns1:camiop> "
                             "<strOp xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">login</strOp> "
                             "<strTessera xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"/> "
                             "<anyParametri xsi:type=\"ns2:Map\"> "
                             "<item> "
                             "<key xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">CRM_USERNAME</key> "
                             "<value xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">%@</value> "
                             "</item> "
                             "<item> "
                             "<key xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">CRM_PASSWORD</key> "
                             "<value xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">%@</value> "
                             "</item> "
                             "<item> "
                             "<key xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">CRM_SITEAPP</key> "
                             "<value xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">2</value> "
                             "</item> "
                             "</anyParametri> "
                             "</ns1:camiop> "
                             "</SOAP-ENV:Body> "
                             "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope> ", _outTxtuser.text, _outTxtpass.text];


    NSLog(@"REQUEST = %@", soapMessage);


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://srvb.mysite.com/dbmgr.class.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"srvbop" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];



    if(theConnection)
    {
        //webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        NSLog(@"theConnection OK");

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is null");
    }

}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response
{
    [_webData setLength:0];
    NSHTTPURLResponse * httpResponse;

    httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

    NSLog(@"HTTP error %zd", (ssize_t) httpResponse.statusCode);

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    [_webData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"DID RECEIVE DATA");

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"error with the connection");
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received bytes %d", [_webData length]);
    //NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[_webData mutableBytes] length:[_webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"xml %@",theXML);

    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: _webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    _webData = nil;

    NSLog(@"Response: %@", theXML);
    [_outLabelrich setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Response: %@", theXML]];

    /*xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];

    [xmlParser parse];
     */
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{



    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Symbol"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"Last"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"Time"] )
    {
        if(!_soapResults)
        {
            _soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        }
        recordResults = YES;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if(recordResults)
    {
        [_soapResults appendString:string];
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Symbol"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"Last"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"Time"] )
    {
        recordResults = NO;
        NSLog(@"%@", _soapResults);
        _soapResults = nil;
    }
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)backgroundClick:(id)sender {
    [_outTxtuser resignFirstResponder];
    [_outTxtpass resignFirstResponder];
}
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not directly answering your question, but I would highly recommend against writing custom networking/parsing code when there are a number of well developed and highly tested libraries that can handle the dirty work for you.  Check out [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), it will handle the dirty work of the connections and XML parsing for you, while using the convenience of blocks.

For example, here's the AFNetworking equivalent of accessing and parsing a JSON resource (substitute AFXMLRequestOperation for AFJSONRequestOperation in your case)

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"App.net Global Stream: %@", JSON);
} failure:nil];
[operation start];
```